# Proxying std::function via inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, function-pointers, std-function

I'm dealing with raw function pointers that can be invalid (point to an incorrect function) / null if the application (source not available) I am interfacing with updates. I want to create a class that would inherit std::function which would overload operator() and send a message to stdout whenever the class was called, then calling the original function pointer. This would be done so I would be able to easily isolate which function would crash because of a null call. I am not worried about overhead as this would be available in Debug mode only with the use of _DEBUG

Because the STL implementation is up to the compiler and inheriting from it is typically a bad idea I am unsure as to how to do this. The compiler I am using is MSVC (2015).

How would I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just write a wrapper around then?

Comment: because in Release mode I want it to be the original std::function, writing a wrapper would require me to implement all the functions that std::function has. Eg: #ifdef _DEBUG using FunctionPointer = DebugFunction; #else using FunctionPointer = std::function; #endif

Answer (score 0):

```
template < typename Signature >
struct function_decorator
{
    template < typename Fun >
    function_decorator(Fun f)
        : fun(f)
    {}

    template < typename ... Pack >
    auto operator()(Pack ... args) const
    {
        return fun(std::forward<Pack>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::function<Signature> fun;
};
```

For a quick and dirty implementation I think would work.

Comment: You may want to `return fun(std::forward<Pack>(args)...);` for perfect forwarding.